# react-css-modules with decorators not working

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

Trying to get decorator syntax working for react css modules as shown here.
https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#decorator

I've got react-css-modules working using the function syntax, e.g.

`CSSModules(Table, styles)`

but when using decorators, e.g.

`@CSSModules(styles)`

`export default class extends React.Component {}`

nothing seems to be instantiated and no errors are thrown either. I've got the babel-plugin-syntax-decorators loaded.

What could I be missing? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to use that syntax too. It seems that react-scripts uses some babel plugin for running typescript, and that plugin isn't much typescript. So if you're using react-scripts with typescript, consider that it's not "full" typescript, and there is some stuff not working as you could expect.

Also, you can consider using [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles) instead of react-css-modules. It's much simpler, doesn't require any changes in your project at all, and `PatchStyles` provides the same with a lot simpler react component.